# Is there any format change in block #498557

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

I wrote some python code to parse the block data, all the result are fine, until block01095.dat, block #498557.

The code to deal with Transaction is:

```
class Tx: 
  def __init__(self, blockchain):
    start_pos = blockchain.tell()
    self.version = uint4(blockchain)
    check_pos = blockchain.tell()
    # For segwit
    # https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction
    dummy1 = uint1(blockchain)
    dummy2 = uint1(blockchain)
    if dummy1 != 0 or dummy2 != 1:
      blockchain.seek(check_pos)
    self.inCount = varint(blockchain)
    self.inputs = []
    self.seq = 1
    for i in range(0, self.inCount):
      self.inputs.append(TxInput(blockchain, i))
    self.outCount = varint(blockchain)
    self.outputs = []
    if self.outCount > 0:
      for i in range(0, self.outCount):
        self.outputs.append(TxOutput(blockchain, i))
    # For segwit
    if dummy1 == 0 and dummy2 == 1:
      for i in range(0, self.inCount): 
        num_op = uint1(blockchain)
        for n in range(0, num_op):
          op_code=uint1(blockchain)
          _ = hashStr(blockchain.read(op_code))
    self.lockTime = uint4(blockchain)
    cur_pos = blockchain.tell()
    blockchain.seek(start_pos)
    self.raw_bytes = blockchain.read(cur_pos - start_pos)
    self.tx_hash = hash_tx(self.raw_bytes)
    print(self.tx_hash)
```

Full code is in:
https://github.com/keviny/bitcoin-block-parser/blob/master/block.py

The last transaction in #498556 is https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/0baa42c9852b4edd9437e8c3fd38bd0dd89d977fe80ac7648961cf8ff33a2dbf
which is ok to parse.

But in #498557 I can never create the right tx hash anymore. 
The first tx hash I get from block #498557 is 
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/2da60422e1de3e8e64742bb16db5d1e3b2a9813f754cff416e549d570b2ad0e8
which is not a valid tx hash in blockchain.info.

Actually, the first three hash I got are:
2da60422e1de3e8e64742bb16db5d1e3b2a9813f754cff416e549d570b2ad0e8
e0a7e07ccb9b126bd20b5b134d41ec5f8b70bdb5408a263619ca3b8b3a90512d
6c695c567d14bce39a8e58359a2a5d26dc2bcbd9a83f043b5dbc1800c56f84c8
None of above can be used in blockchain.info.

I suspect there is some format change from this block.

Does Anyone here know any background about this issue?

Comment: How are you generating the tx hash? Any code you can provide?

Comment: @JBaczuk Update the code and link in the question.

Comment: Are you saying that 2da6... is the hash you compute for the block's coinbase transaction?

Comment: Yes, the first three tx hash I got are: 
 2da60422e1de3e8e64742bb16db5d1e3b2a9813f754cff416e549d570b2ad0e8  
e0a7e07ccb9b126bd20b5b134d41ec5f8b70bdb5408a263619ca3b8b3a90512d  
6c695c567d14bce39a8e58359a2a5d26dc2bcbd9a83f043b5dbc1800c56f84c8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, by testing your script, is that it is failing on Segwit transactions. This would make sense, if you haven't accounted for it, because it changes what is used to produce the `tx hash`. This was introduced with [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#specification). Currently, not all transactions are required to be in this format, so you will have to account for both. The `txid` still uses the entire transaction structure, this is why you might notice bitcoin-core rpc calls will return a different `txid` than the `tx hash` (`wtxid`) for segwit transactions.

> Definition of **txid** remains unchanged: the double SHA256 of the
>   traditional serialization format:
>
> `[nVersion][txins][txouts][nLockTime]`
>
> A new **wtxid** is defined: the double SHA256 of the new serialization
>   with witness data:
>
> `[nVersion][marker][flag][txins][txouts][witness][nLockTime]`

see [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#specification)

What you'll need to do is look for the segwit flag `0x01` in the serialized transaction. It's an optional 2-byte array right after the first version bytes, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

Comment: Actualloy, You can see I hash the content from tx start to locktime. It looks is compatible with BIP141.
self.raw_bytes = blockchain.read(cur_pos - start_pos)
self.tx_hash = hash_tx(self.raw_bytes)

Comment: Fixed, we should use varint but int1 to parse the witness. Thanks!